# How to enable SSL on a server that is on a private network using openssl?

Tags: ssl, openssl

### Context

I'm trying to install a frontend & backend api(with ssl) on a client's on-prem environment.
I was able to generate a self-signed ssl certificate using openssl, but when the front end application makes a request to the api I get ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID.

**Do you need to use a real domain for a non self-signed ssl certificate?**

I tried generating a non self-signed ssl certificate using openssl, but I dont have a domain to use because the api is not public. Can I use a dummy one or does it matter what I use?

**All of the examples I've seen don't use a subdomain, can I use one?**

I plan on hitting the api by using the private ip, but also don't know if I should request a private dns entry from my client to get this done.

I used the company's domain when creating the non self-signed ssl certificate but I wasn't able to create one. I was reading that the server has to have port 80/443 open so that openssl can confirm you own the server. **Will the ssl certificate work if I open those ports to generate the ssl certificate and then close them after?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you need to use a real domain for a non self-signed ssl
> certificate?

Yes you need real domain.

> All of the examples I've seen don't use a subdomain, can I use one?

Yes you can generate certificate for subdomain.

> Will the ssl certificate work if I open those ports to generate the
> ssl certificate and then close them after?

There is multiple way to prove that domain is yours. For some of them you don't need to open those ports.

If you want to use self-signed domain, you just need to import certification authority  which was used for signing to avoid ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error.

Comment: if i use the port option will it still work if i close them after?

Comment: Yes it will work until expiration day of generated certificate. For letsencrypt it is 90 days. After this time you need to renew certificate.